# Window.open only if the window is not open

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have a link on my site that opens a new window to a page that plays a very long audio file. My current script works fine to open the page and not refresh if the link is clicked multiple times. However, when I have moved to a seperate page on my site and click this link again, it reloads. I am aware that when the parent element changes, I will lose my variable and thus I will need to open the window, overiding the existing content. I am trying to find a solution around that. I would prefer not to use a cookie to achieve this, but I will if required.

My script is as follows:

```
function OpenWindow(){
    if(typeof(winRef) == 'undefined' || winRef.closed){
    //create new
    winRef = window.open('http://samplesite/page','winPop','sampleListOfOptions');
    } else {
    //give it focus (in case it got burried)
     winRef.focus();
    } 
}
```

Comment: A cookie or a server-side session value will be needed, for what you've stated, you'll lost all variables in the parent page upon navigate away.

Comment: Did you try first to call `winRef = window.open("", "winPopup")` (this should return a window, if it exists, without reloading), and only if winRef is `null`, then create new window `window.open("http://url", "winPopup", "params")`?

Comment: Can you please show me how that would look in my function?

Comment: @TylerDemerchant, you didn't mention me in comment so I didn't get notification ;-). I'm posting the answer now... It's done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first to call `winRef = window.open("", "winPopup")` without URL - this will return a window, if it exists, without reloading. And only if `winRef` is `null` or empty window, then create new window.

Here is my test code:

```
var winRef;

function OpenWindow()
{
  if(typeof(winRef) == 'undefined' || winRef.closed)
  {
    //create new
    var url = 'http://someurl';
    winRef = window.open('', 'winPop', 'sampleListOfOptions');
    if(winRef == null || winRef.document.location.href != url)
    {
      winRef = window.open(url, 'winPop');
    }
  }
  else
  {
    //give it focus (in case it got burried)
    winRef.focus();
  } 
}
```

It works.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me it only worked in Chrome and IE(9), not in Firefox(26).

Comment: @GeorgiyIvankin, I think you may post a new question and provide details of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Stan and http://ektaraval.blogspot.ca/2011/05/how-to-set-focus-to-child-window.html

My solution creates a breakout pop-up mp3 player that remains active site wide and only refreshes if the window is not open prior to clicking the link button

```
function OpenWindow(){
    var targetWin = window.open('','winPop', 'sample-options');
    if(targetWin.location == 'about:blank'){
        //create new
        targetWin.location.href = 'http://site/megaplayer';
        targetWin.focus();
    } else {
        //give it focus (in case it got burried)
        targetWin.focus();
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Stan - This is what I had come up with prior to seeing your response. I think we were both posting at the same time. Is there any particular reason why I should use your example instead of mine?

Comment: No, I think yours is ok. Mine is just a fast example written as soon as I've spotted your comment which was lacking for @username ;-), it's just to show you main idea, and your variant follows it perfectly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, after navigating away from original page you're losing track of what windows you may have opened.

As far as I can tell, there's no way to "regain" reference to that particular window. You may (using cookies, server side session or whatever) know that window was opened already, but you won't ever have a direct access to it from different page (even on the same domain). This kind of communication between already opened windows may be simulated with help of ajax and server side code, that would serve as agent when sharing some information between two windows. It's not an easy nor clean solution however.

Comment: Please see above solution it work so this Answer is invalid.